# Lacking information on a Calculus Problem, have $f(x)$ need ${{dg} \over {dx}}$?

Tags: calculus

I am a senior in high school taking an AP Calc AB class. The textbook I am using is Calculus Concepts and Calculators (second edition) distributed by Venture Publishing.

I am utterly stuck on question 18.

> 18. Let *f*(*x*) = int(*x*).
>
> a) Explain why *g'*(2.5) = 0.
>
> b) Explain why *g'*(2) does not exist.

I am flummoxed mainly because I was only given the function *f* of *x* and there is no mention of a function *g* of *x* anywhere in the given information.

In addition, my TI-84 Plus calculator, when that equation is plugged in, the graph reads 2 in both of the stated x-inputs.

Can you please help me?
Thanks, Nefer007

Comment: It almost certainly should say "Let $g(x) = \mathrm{int}(x)$." I presume $\mathrm{int}(x)$ is the greatest integer function. You can check differentiability rather easily at $2$ and $2.5$.

Comment: Yeah, almost certainly a typo. $f = g$.

Comment: Check  for $ f(x) = 1/ \sin \pi x $

Comment: Use the mean value theorem to show part (a). Then for part (b), show that $g(x)$ is not continuous at $x=2$. For if $g(x)$ was differentiable at $x=2$ then it would be continuous there also, when it's not continuous.

Comment: Mean... value theorem? Never heard of it, can we go over that please? I get the second part now, though, but *g'*(2.5) is not 0, it's 2.